# Reg Expression Formula

Tags: regex

I am having trouble developing a regex for the following scenario.

Example Text: `'5-5-14'!Sum(A1:B2)+Sum(C1:C2)+5-10/20`

When I loop through my regex formula, I only want to find instances of `+#` or `-#` but if the `-#` or `+#` is within single quotes, to ignore.

So with my example, my results would ignore `-5` and `-14` and only return the `+5` and `-10`

Is this possible? Thank you for your help!

Comment: What regex engine are you using? Regex engines supporting lookbehind tend to make this more easy.

Comment: Yes, I am using VBA, the Object name is "VBScript.RegExp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[+-]\d+(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pG1kU1/15